# How to improve performance for oftenly using bitmaps in c#?

Tags: c#, singleton, buffer, image-caching

I am trying to make an image checker. Basically it checks a big image (usually changes) contain an img (never changes) or not. So, to imporve performance, i'm looking for a way to keep this image on memory so i don't go to the disc everytime for it.

```
Bitmap img = Accord.Imaging.Image.FromFile(@"D:\img.png");
```

Is there any good solution for this? Singleton pattern is good choice for me? Any running examples?

> EDIT-1: WPF project.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it would be best to avoid using static/singleton patterns (as always it's best to avoid using them). You could write some Repository with this Bitmap loaded in the creation and then store it in some higher-level of the classes you're using. But sometimes it's a good way to check the Singleton :)
Here is a basic thread-safe singleton pattern (with Bitmap inside):

```
class Singleton
{
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }

    private Singleton() { }

    private static Singleton _instance;

    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    public static Singleton GetInstance(Bitmap value = null)
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new Singleton();
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                      _instance.Image = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }     
}
```

(Taken from one of the best pages in Software Development snippets: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/csharp/example#example-1)

Then your first load would be:

```
var  singleton = Singleton.GetInstance(Accord.Imaging.Image.FromFile(@"D:\img.png"));
```

And each next:

```
var image = Singleton.GetInstance().Image;
```